# What country is Tarsia / טרסי?

Tags: purim, language, tractate-megillah

In Bavli [Megilla 13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13b.10-11?lang=bi), we are told that Bigtan and Teresh were two טרסיים, translated by R. Steinsaltz as Tarsians. We are told that they spoke in the Tarsian language.

In what modern country or region was Tarsia located, and are there any surviving writings of this Tarsian language which are available today?

Comment: Tarsian language part May be off topic

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a variant of [Tarsus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsus,_Mersin) which was a major historical city which still exists in modern day Turkey. The other spelling variant  in Hebrew is תרשיש. That is also how it is listed in [Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%98%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B4%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B5%D7%9C?lang=bi).

Here is the Wikipedia page giving some background.

Answer (score 0):

[Living Torah, Gen. 10:](https://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=1&CHAPTER=10#C117)

> In 1 Chronicles 1:7, it is Tarshishah. It was famed for its ships, see 1 Kings 10:22, 22:49, etc. Also see Isaiah 23;10, 66:19, Ezekiel 38:13, Jonah 1:3. Josephus identifies it with Cilicia, whose capital was Tarsus. The identification with Tarsus is also upheld in Talmudic sources (Targum Yonathan; Yerushalmi, Megilla 1:9).
>
> Some associate it with Tuscany, Lombardi, Florence and Milan (Abarbanel. Cf. Sefer HaYashar).