# What/Where is Tarshish

Tags: torah-study, purim, megillat-esther, geography

Springboarding from a conversation [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100639/what-country-is-tarsia-%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%99#:%7E:text=The%20other%20spelling%20variant%20in%20Hebrew%20is%20%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9.%20That%20is%20also%20how%20it%20is%20listed%20in%20Jastrow.), is the term "Tarshish" mentioned anywhere (besides Jastrow) in connection with Bigsan and Seresh?

This question is specifically looking to find a way of connecting "Tarshish" with "Bigsan and Seresh".

Comment: Likely either her Tartassus (Spain) or Tarsus (coastal Turkey)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the linked text of BT Megillah 13b? https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13b.10-11?lang=bi

Answer (score 2):

It appears in several places:

In [Tehillim 48:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.48.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it writes:

> בְּר֥וּחַ קָדִ֑ים תְּ֝שַׁבֵּ֗ר אֳנִיּ֥וֹת תַּרְשִֽׁישׁ
>
> As the Tarshish fleet was wrecked in an easterly gale.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Psalms.48.8.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) over there notes:

> אניות תרשיש. הם שכיני צור היא אפריקא ומאדום היא
>
> The ships of Tarshish - They are the neighbors of **[Tyre](https://www.britannica.com/place/Tyre)**, which is Africa, and it is of Edom.

The verse in Tehillim links with the verse in [Melachim I 22:49](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.22.49?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> יְהוֹשָׁפָ֡ט (עשר) [עָשָׂה֩] אֳנִיּ֨וֹת תַּרְשִׁ֜ישׁ לָלֶ֧כֶת אֹפִ֛ירָה לַזָּהָ֖ב וְלֹ֣א הָלָ֑ךְ כִּֽי־[נִשְׁבְּר֥וּ] (נשברה) אֳנִיּ֖וֹת בְּעֶצְי֥וֹן גָּֽבֶר
>
> Yehoshaphat constructed Tarshish ships to sail to Ophir for gold. But he did not sail because the ships were wrecked at Ezion-geber.

This got me searching further, and these ships are mentioned earlier in [10:22](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.10.22?lang=bi):

> כִּי֩ אֳנִ֨י תַרְשִׁ֤ישׁ לַמֶּ֙לֶךְ֙ בַּיָּ֔ם עִ֖ם אֳנִ֣י חִירָ֑ם אַחַת֩ לְשָׁלֹ֨שׁ שָׁנִ֜ים תָּב֣וֹא ׀ אֳנִ֣י תַרְשִׁ֗ישׁ נֹֽשְׂאֵת֙ זָהָ֣ב וָכֶ֔סֶף שֶׁנְהַבִּ֥ים וְקֹפִ֖ים וְתֻכִּיִּֽים
>
> For the king had a Tarshish fleet. Probably a fleet of large ships. on the sea, along with Hiram’s fleet. Once every three years, the Tarshish fleet came in, bearing gold and silver, ivory, apes, and peacocks.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.10.22?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_I_Kings.10.22.1&lang2=bi) there likewise notes:

> אֳנִי תַרְשִׁישׁ. (תַּרְגּוּם:) סְפִינַת אַפְרִיקָא
>
> Ships of Tarshish. [Targum Yonoson rendered,] “ships of Africa.”

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_I_Kings.10.22.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) there provides further information noting one view that it is probably the city of [**Carthage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthage) in North Africa by the Mediterranean Sea. However, if that is the case, he questions how the ships went from Etzyon Gever which is on the shore of the Red Sea to Tarshish, (as per the verse in [Divrei HaYamim II 20:37](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.20.37?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). He therefore reasons (based off Yeshaya 23:10 which details the travelling from Tarshish to Ophir<sup>1</sup>) that it is far more likely to be the city of [**Tarsus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsus,_Mersin) as it is known that the Syrians, when they came to Spain, found refined silver on the face of the earth in great abundance, until they made all their vessels, and also the hooks of their ships  out of silver. There they built up a city of habitation and trade and this city sits at the entrance of the Atlantic Ocean, which the Yam Suf also flows into. Thus, a more realistic geographical location if they travelled from Tarshish to Ophir.

---

<sup>1</sup> It writes [Yehashaya 23:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.23.10?lang=bi)

> עִבְרִ֥י אַרְצֵ֖ךְ כַּיְאֹ֑ר בַּת־תַּרְשִׁ֕ישׁ אֵ֖ין מֵ֥זַח עֽוֹד
>
> Traverse your land like the Nile, Fair Tarshish; This is a harbor no more.

Once again [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Isaiah.23.10.3?lang=bi&with=Tanakh%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en) adds that this Tyre.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned as the destination Yonah HaNavi was trying to flee to, right at the beginning of [Sefer Yonah-](https://www.sefaria.org/texts)Perek 1 passuk 3,

"וַיָּ֤קׇם יוֹנָה֙ לִבְרֹ֣חַ תַּרְשִׁ֔ישָׁה מִלִּפְנֵ֖י יְהֹוָ֑ה וַיֵּ֨רֶד יָפ֜וֹ וַיִּמְצָ֥א אֳנִיָּ֣ה ׀ בָּאָ֣ה תַרְשִׁ֗ישׁ וַיִּתֵּ֨ן שְׂכָרָ֜הּ וַיֵּ֤רֶד בָּהּ֙ לָב֤וֹא עִמָּהֶם֙ תַּרְשִׁ֔ישָׁה מִלִּפְנֵ֖י יְהֹוָֽה׃"

Jonah, however, started out to flee to Tarshish from GOD’s service. He went down to Joppa and found a ship going to Tarshish. He paid the fare and went aboard to sail with the others to Tarshish, away from the service of GOD

(Text and translation Sefaria)

Comment: Do you know if this connected with the language which Bigsan and Seresh were speaking in the megillah.

Comment: Tarshish was a major city in the Ancient World (both the one in Spain and the one in Turkey, most commentaries connect the one in Sefer Yonah and Meguillah Esther to the one in Turkey) and the Tarshish in Turkey was definitely part of Ahashverosh's empire, so a simple reading would be that the city Yonah HaNavi tried to flee to is their hometown.